# How do I know which UIViewController is being picked in a UITabBarController at didSelectItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{

}
```

Basically this is the requirement. If an item is placed I should

do this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=self.Reload;
```

I need to know that user is selecting the right item (#2). The number may change but it should correspond to the one whose object is of type BGCRListOrMapController

Comment: are u aware of the property @property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController *selectedViewController?

Comment: please make your question more clear?

Comment: I want to make it more clear but somebody already have perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the selectedViewController and then test it

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
{
  if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[BGCRListOrMapController class]) {
    viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.Reload;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set yourself as the `UITabBarController`'s delegate

Answer (score 3):

use tags for each tab bar item and in your did select item function read the tag

```
switch(item.tag) {
case 0:
break;
case 1:
do something;
}
```